# how to chang preview of list of articles of one category?

Tags: posts, categories, previews

I have downloaded wp tempalte demo where I have articles dive into different categories. Each category has its own button in main menu. When I click to show the category, list of its articles are show different foreach category.
Where can I set how to show list of articles / category?

Comment: do you mean http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates ?

Comment: It seems this is just what Im looking for. I just neet to finish my reading to make sure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the setting in WP -> Theme Panel -> Categories